# Display other text centered

Tags: overlays

I'd like to find all occurrences of `==` in a buffer and overlay them with Unicode `≡`, keeping width of two chars and centered in the space.

I know about replacing text visual representation:

```
(put-text-property 1 10 'display "replacement")
```

about keeping known width

```
(put-text-property 1 10 'display '(space :width (119)))
```

I do not know how to put this together and keep it centered.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but one option would be to create a custom XPM image that is the width of two characters and center that image when designing it.  You can have a function that calculates and adds/removes pixels / columns as needed based upon the frame character width, and frame character height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While my solution doesn't really center, it comes close enough I hope. There is a display property that adjusts the width of all spaces, if I use the string `≡` and make its spaces half the width, it will look centered and two characters wide.  The only downside I could find so far is that putting the cursor on the propertized string highlights its first space.

Here's a demonstration that should produce two lines of code lining up perfectly upon evaluating it with C-x C-e and point after the end of the expression:

```
(insert "\na == b\n"
        "a " (propertize "=" 'display
                         (propertize " ≡ " 'display '(space-width 0.5)))
        " b\n")
```

Comment: By judicious use of the `cursor` text-property, you should be able to make Emacs draw the cursor over the ≡ sign instead of drawing it over the preceding space.

Comment: @Stefan I doubt it's worth it though.